# When wrapping text (or a tcolorbox) around a table, how do I make it stop?

Tags: tcolorbox, wrapfigure

I have elements that are supposed to be wrapped around a table, but it's almost like the table has just made its own column and nothing else will show up underneath that table now. Here's what it looks like:
[image: tcolorbox still wrapping after table has ended]

Everything is basically in the spot I want it to be in, but I'm not sure why the tcolorbox won't stretch the entire way across the page or how to make it do so. Here's the code I'm using (yes I know there was a much easier way to make the table look the way I want).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{wraptable}{r}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c | ccc | ccc| ccc|ccc|ccc|} 
\hline
 $t$ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline
\hline
$x$&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline
$y$ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&& \\[0.5ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}

\noindent $x=\frac{1}{2}t^3-6t$\\
$y=\frac{1}{2}t^2$
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{48656_graph_1010a_md.png}
\end{center}\\
\vspace{.4cm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{Graphing parametric equations on a graphing calculator}
\begin{itemize}
    \item put your calculator in parametric mode (MODE $\rightarrow$ switch from FUNC to PAR)
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Any input would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It would be easier to address this question if you provided a full, compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  Since different document classes interact differently with the packages you use (but don't explicitly identify), at least that information is necessary.

Comment: You need to specify the number of lines (optional argument) to be [3].  The image counts as one line.